# store logo in not loading

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, command-line, logo, default.xml

I am overwriting my theme logo in my child theme with the `default.xml` file but the logo is not loading in the storefront.

This is my `default.xml` code:

```
<referenceBlock name="logo">
      <arguments>
         <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">images/my-store-logo.jpg</argument>
         <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">30</argument>
         <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">30</argument>
      </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

My console shows following `url` for the `image`:

```
<img src="https://localhost/magento/pub/static/version1583882139/frontend/Custom/less/en_US/images/my- 
store-logo.jpg" title="" alt="" width="30" height="30">
```

When i click on the above link it shows the following `error message` on the new page:

```
A symlink for "C:/xampp/htdocs/magento/app/design/frontend/Custom/theme-custom- 
less/web/images/my-store-logo.jpg" can't be created and placed to 
"C:/xampp/htdocs/magento/pub/static/frontend/Custom/less/en_US/images/my-store-logo.jpg". 
Warning!symlink(): Cannot create symlink, error code(1314)
```

This is my `store front` view:
[image: This is my <code>store front</code> view:]

Thanks in advance.

**Edit: This is my directory structure:**

[image: directory structure]

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: yes, it was resolved.

Comment: I see that none of the answers here were accepted. Can you share how you fixed it? Perhaps write up an answer to your original question?

Comment: Good, I'll write up the different scenarios that cause this.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct and must be inserted in

> /Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

It seems that your static image is in a less folder(?), is your static file well generated?

You can read https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html#theme_logo

Answer (score 1):

**Declaration of Theme Logo**

Go to app/design/frontend/Demo/Mytheme/Magento_Theme/layout and create a default.xml file. Paste the following code in it:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
<referenceBlock name="logo">
<arguments>
<argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">images/mytheme-logo.png</argument>
<argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">200</argument>
<argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">200</argument>
</arguments>
</referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

**Upload Theme Logo**

Go to app/design/frontend/Demo/Mytheme/web/images and upload your logo (mytheme-logo.png) here.

**Apply Your Theme**

- Open the Admin panel of your Magento 2 and go to Content →
  Configuration.
- Click on the Edit option.
- Select Mytheme from the Applied Theme drop-down menu and click on
  Save Configuration.